# Unknown extension installing with my project in all folders

Tags: reactjs

[screenshot of extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9XHF.jpg)

Please see attached image.

Does any one know why i am getting the duplicate file extensions in my project folders?
._App, ._Form, ._TextBox, ._Counter

Can i get rid of them?

I tried deleting them but they keep reappearing whenever i start the project again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.